# RGBDSLAM_v2 save Octomap at a particular z value

Tags: slam, navigation, octomap, 3d-slam, rgbdslamv2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As stated in the title, is there a way to save octomap(GUI or commandline) at a particular z value? Is there a way to do it by tweaking either the launch files or source code? If so, where to locate these files?

I am currently running roslaunch rgbdslam openni+rgbdslam.launch, and then saving the octomap using the GUI. The reason why only a particular z value is desired is because the generation of full octomap takes quite some time, and I'm thinking of ways to shorten the time required.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256042/rgbdslam_v2-save-octomap-at-a-particular-z-value/) by [cj](https://answers.ros.org/users/29542/cj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the rgbdslam_v2 source code, check out the method GraphManager::firstNode(...) in graph_manager.cpp. There, the reference_pose is set (to identity).

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2017-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0